# Как зашифровать ключи строк в strings.xml

Tags: android, xml

Как можно заменить все ключи к строкам, к которым ссылаются с java... К примеру string name="lock" -> string name="a1". Работаю в Android Studio..

Comment: [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: вам нужно переименовать какое то количество идентификаторов строк в проекте или во время работы приложения что то делать с ними?

Comment: Именно в проекте, чтобы после компиляции были зашифрованые имена этих ключей..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10220069/does-proguard-work-to-obfuscate-static-string-constants